# Add various classes with jquery, one of them being a var

Tags: jquery, var, addclass

This keeps on throwing an error, is there a way to put two or more classes in the same "bracket" when one is a var?

```
$("#test a").click(function(){
  var $color =  $(this, "p").text()
  $("#left-part").removeClass().addClass("ClassnameX" $color);
});
```

Comment: This is just weird ... what is it you want to achieve? If `$color` was, for example, equal to "whatever", would you like to literally get `class="$color whatever"`?

Comment: How about `.addclass($color).addclass("myClass")`

Comment: I think you mean `$('p', this).text()`, otherwise you're looking for an element you already have a reference to via `this`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is syntax error in the `.addClass("$color" $color)`

Directly pass the variable to your method

```
 $("#left-part").removeClass().addClass("$color").addClass($color);
```

*OR*, using string concatenation

```
$("#left-part").removeClass().addClass("$color " + $color);
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I did not know I had to use the + in this context !